# Pass a MemoryStream to razor View as Session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am currently using Viewbag to pass my stream across to the view but I suspect that this is the reason my file is not loading in the document viewer control i'm using.

To verify I want to pass my memorystream across as a session variable but am unsure how to do this.

So far in the Controller I have got my memorystream (verified to be working) and created the session var like so:

```
Session["fStream"] = strm;
```

and am trying to access it in my razor view like:

```
Html.Gnostice().DocumentViewer(oViewerSettings).LoadDocument(@Session["PDFLink"]).Render();
```

which results in the error message

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from object to System.IO.Stream
```

Thanks

Comment: Not a good approach, but anyway; you will need to cast it

Comment: The `Session[string]` indexer returns an `object` that you'll need to cast to the appropriate type. But you don't want to use streams in session variables, as a stream is not serializable. Instead let your view load the stream directly from an action method, for example through an AJAX request.

Comment: Do either of you know if there are known issues with passing Memorystreams across with Viewbag?  @MarkHomer should I cast it in the view, or the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Examples of how you could approach this,

(1) "strm" is an integer.

```
Convert.ToInt32(Request["fStream"])
```

(2) Bool

```
Convert.ToBoolean(Request["fStream"])
```

(3) Bool Optional

```
 Request["fStream"].AsBool()
```

(4) String

```
Request["fStream"].ToString()
```

(5) String Option 2

```
Convert.ToString(Request["fStream"])
```

I personally prefer the "Convert." which is straightforward and readable.